# Methods: Identifier expected

Tags: java

I've tried looking for answers on here in other threads but I still can't seem to figure it out. I get a  error:  expected at the line private static int getUserMHR(age). Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2
{
//class variables
//a scanner object to read input from the keyboard - can be used by any method
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String name; // the user's name
  int age; // the user's age
  String gender; // the user's gender
  float height; // the users height in inches
  float weight; // the users weight in pounds
  int mhr; //the user's maximum heart rate
  int thr; //the user's target heart rate
  float bmi; //the user's body mass index

  //display the purpose of the program
  displayPurpose();
  //get the user's name
  name = getUserName();
  //get the user's age
  age = getUserAge();
  //get the user's gender
  gender = getUserGender();
  //get the user's height
  height = getUserHeight();
  //get the user's weight
  weight = getUserWeight();
  //get the user's maximum heart private
  mhr = getUserMHR();

   System.out.println(mhr);

}// of main

private static void displayPurpose()
{
    System.out.println("****************************************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("            This application takes the user's name, age, gender, height and weight");
    System.out.println("It then display's the user's maximum heart rate, target heart rate, BMI (Body Mass Index), and their");
    System.out.println("                                              weight class");
    System.out.println("****************************************************************************************************");
}//displayPurpose

private static String getUserName()
{
  //local variable
  String username;

  //ask for user's name
  System.out.println("Please input your name: ");
  //input the user's name
  username = input.nextLine();

  //return user's name
  return username;

}//getUserName();

private static int getUserAge()
{
  //local variable
  int userage;

  //ask for user's age
  System.out.println("Please input your age: ");
  //input the user's age
  userage = input.nextByte();

  //return user's age
  return userage;
}//getUserAge();

private static String getUserGender()
{
  //local variable
  String gender;

  //ask for user's gender
  System.out.println("Please input your gender (M or F): ");
  //input the user's gender
  gender = input.nextLine();

  //return user's gender
  return gender;
}//getUserGender();

private static float getUserHeight()
{
  //local variable
  float height;

  //ask for user's height
  System.out.println("Please input your height (in inches): ");
  //input the user's height
  height = input.nextFloat();

  //return user's height
  return height;
}//getUserHeight();

private static float getUserWeight()
{
  //local variable
  float weight;

  //ask for user's weight
  System.out.println("Please input your weight (in pounds): ");
  //input the user's weights
  weight = input.nextFloat();

  //return user's weight
  return weight;
}//getUserWeight();

private static int getUserMHR(age)
{
  int mhrcalc;
  mhrcalc = (age - 220); //calculate the user's maximum heart private

  return mhrcalc;
}
```

}

I've tried putting an int before age and getting rid of the int from the actual method but nothing seems to work. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: You need to specify the data type of the `age` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what type `age` is, here it's `int` :

```
private static int getUserMHR(int age){
  int mhrcalc;
  mhrcalc = (age - 220); //calculate the user's maximum heart private
  return mhrcalc;
}
```

And as you ask for an argument, you need to give it when you call the method

```
mhr = getUserMHR(age);
```

---

*Also you don't need to split declaration and assignation everyime (here it's seems you want to be specifif on comment so ok)* `int t;  t=5; ==> int t=5;`

Comment: I know I said this to the other answer but, I've tried doing this but then I get the error method getUserMHR in class Assignment2 cannot be applied to given types; mhr = getUserMHR(); and when i try to look up what the problem is the solution seems to be to get rid of the int before age which then gets me stuck in this loop of errors

Comment: @MasonFerrie I've edit, you need to pass `age` to the method as the method ask for it

Comment: And with that the problem is solved! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your method getUserMHR has the single parameter age. But in Java you have to specify the type of the parameters. Since the age is most likely an integer you can just use the primitive type int.

```
private static int getUserMHR( int age ) { //... }
```

Comment: I've tried doing this but then I get the error  method getUserMHR in class Assignment2 cannot be applied to given types; mhr = getUserMHR(); and when i try to look up what the problem is the solution seems to be to get rid of the int before age which then gets me stuck in this loop of errors